# Wrong on summation of two columns

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

I have created **Table** `production_report`

| pro_id | pro_stage_id | pro_model_id | pro_qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 44 | 420 |
| 2 | 1 | 44 | 200 |
| 3 | 1 | 44 | 430 |

**Table** `production_defects_report`

| pdr_id | prd_modet_id | pdr_stage_id | pdr_defect_id | pdr_qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 44 | 1 | 2 | 123 |
| 2 | 44 | 1 | 2 | 123 |

**Table** `model_details`

| modet_id | modet_name |
| --- | --- |
| 44 | 22955 TMR5 BLUE |

**Table** `stages`

| st_id | st_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Prepare Material |
| 2 | Testing |

**Table** `defects`

| def_id | def_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Broken Head |
| 2 | Lose power |

I need to know the summation of pro_qty and the pdr_qty to know how much produced and how many defects founded  after testing such as the following table

| Model Name | Stage Name | Produced Quantity | Defect Name | Quantity of defects | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22955 TMR5 BLUE | Prepare Material | 1050 | Lose power | 246 | 35.14 |

I have created a Model to get and summation in QTY from both tables as the below function

```
public function getCombinedReport() {
        $this->db->select('md.modet_desc AS model_name, s.st_name AS stage_name, SUM(pr.pro_qty) AS total_pro_qty, d.def_name AS defect_name, COALESCE(SUM(pdr.pdr_qty), 0) AS total_pdr_qty');
        $this->db->from('production_report AS pr');
        $this->db->join('model_details AS md', 'pr.pro_model_id = md.modet_id');
        $this->db->join('stages AS s', 'pr.pro_stage_id = s.st_id');
        $this->db->join('production_defects_report AS pdr', 'pr.pro_model_id = pdr.pdr_modet_id AND pr.pro_stage_id = pdr.pdr_stage_id');
        $this->db->join('defects AS d', 'pdr.pdr_defect_id = d.def_id');
        $this->db->group_by('pr.pro_model_id, pr.pro_stage_id, d.def_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

The problem i found it returns the summation of *pro_qty* and *pdr_qty* multiplied by the counted rows of other joined tables. such as the following table.

| Model Name | Stage Name | Produced Quantity | Defect Name | Quantity of defects | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22955 TMR5 BLUE | Prepare Material | 2100 | Lose power | 738 | 35.1% |

I want to generate a report to know how many defects for each stage in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the wrong results because you have multiple rows with the same `model_id` and `stage_id` in the `production_report` table, and also multiple rows with the same `model_id`, `stage_id` and `defect_id` in the `production_defects_report` table. If you then join these two tables on `model_id` and `stage_id`, sql calculates all possible combinations of rows from the `production_report` and `production_defects_report` table where the `model_id` and `stage_id` match, and that causes it to duplicate rows. If you then sum the rows you also count the duplicates.

What you could do, is first group the `production_report` table on `model_id` and `stage_id` and calculate the quanties for each group, and also group the `production_defects_report` table on `model_id`, `stage_id` and `defect_id` and calculate the quantities for each group, before joining the two tables. Then there will no longer be multiple rows with the same `model_id` and `stage_id` (unless the `defect_id` is different, but I suppose you do want a separate row in that case) so sql will no longer duplicate the rows and since you've already done the summation before the join, you don't need to group and sum in the outer query anymore either. Query:

```
SELECT md.modet_name, s.st_name AS stage_name, pr.sum_pro_qty AS total_pro_qty, d.def_name AS defect_name, COALESCE(pdr.sum_pdr_qty, 0) AS total_pdr_qty
FROM (SELECT pro_model_id, pro_stage_id, SUM(pro_qty) AS sum_pro_qty
    FROM production_report
    GROUP BY pro_model_id, pro_stage_id) AS pr
JOIN model_details AS md ON pr.pro_model_id = md.modet_id
JOIN stages AS s ON pr.pro_stage_id = s.st_id
JOIN (SELECT pdr_modet_id, pdr_stage_id, pdr_defect_id, SUM(pdr_qty) AS sum_pdr_qty
    FROM production_defects_report 
    GROUP BY pdr_modet_id, pdr_stage_id, pdr_defect_id) AS pdr
ON pr.pro_model_id = pdr.pdr_modet_id AND pr.pro_stage_id = pdr.pdr_stage_id
JOIN defects AS d ON pdr.pdr_defect_id = d.def_id
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8DgUxDDZ3Jda4U6fwgiL6t/0 (Click "run" in the top bar to see the result.)

In CodeIgniter 3:

```
$this->db->query(
    'SELECT md.modet_name, s.st_name AS stage_name, pr.sum_pro_qty AS total_pro_qty, d.def_name AS defect_name, COALESCE(pdr.sum_pdr_qty, 0) AS total_pdr_qty
    FROM (SELECT pro_model_id, pro_stage_id, SUM(pro_qty) AS sum_pro_qty
        FROM production_report
        GROUP BY pro_model_id, pro_stage_id) AS pr
    JOIN model_details AS md ON pr.pro_model_id = md.modet_id
    JOIN stages AS s ON pr.pro_stage_id = s.st_id
    JOIN (SELECT pdr_modet_id, pdr_stage_id, pdr_defect_id, SUM(pdr_qty) AS sum_pdr_qty
        FROM production_defects_report 
        GROUP BY pdr_modet_id, pdr_stage_id, pdr_defect_id) AS pdr
    ON pr.pro_model_id = pdr.pdr_modet_id AND pr.pro_stage_id = pdr.pdr_stage_id
    JOIN defects AS d ON pdr.pdr_defect_id = d.def_id'
)->result();
```